# Is there a better way to do this in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Actually this currently doesnt work at all

```
 @category = Category.find(params[:id])
 @sub_categories = @category.sub_categories
 if @sub_categories
  @designs = []
  @sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
    @designs << sub_cat.designs.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'name', :per_page => @per_page
  end
end
```

Its failing on this syntax error

```
categories_controller.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kEND
...<< sub_cat.designs.paginate :page => params[:page], :order ...
```

Basically i have category has many sub_categories which has many designs and its on the current category and I want to show all the designs for that category...any idea on best practices and how too fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do two things to refactor this...

First is to reduce coupling by moving the pagination options to a class method on the design model. Your controller shouldn't know this much about the design model.

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.paginate_with_params(params, per_page)
    paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => 'name', :per_page => per_page)
  end
end
```

Second is to remove the unnecessary variables and logic from your controller that don't really add much value:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@designs = @category.sub_categories.map |sub_cat|
  sub_cat.designs.paginate_with_params(params, @per_page)
end
```

I haven't tested this code, so please go easy on me if it doesn't work :)

Comment: fix: "<<" as inheritance symbol

Comment: @Daniel: what do you mean that "<<" is a fix, can you explain

Comment: @Matt - I fixed it, I had << instead of <

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant to use `@designs` rather than `@patterns`:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@sub_categories = @category.sub_categories
pagination_options = { :page => params[:page],
                       :order => 'name',
                       :per_page => @per_page
                     }
unless @sub_categories.empty?
  @designs = []
  @sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
    @designs << sub_cat.designs.paginate(pagination_options)
  end
end
```

I think what was missing were the brackets for the arguments to the `paginate` call.

Comment: Why do you reckon it was failing in the first place? Because it didn't know what were parameters to `paginate` and what was parameters to `<<`?

Comment: one problem with this is that now the loop in the view is giving me errors because it looping through will_paginate objects and here is my error undefined method `name' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x103339fb0>

Comment: fixed the first issue with a flatten but now i am getting   undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x1036be208> Extracted source (around line #37): 37: <%= will_paginate @designs %>

Answer (score 1):

```
a = []
b.each do |c|
    a << c.d(e)
end
```

Is equal to:

```
a = b.map { |c| c.d(e) }
```

And if `d` doesn't need parameters:

```
a = b.map &:d
```

But in your case, I guess, you just need to add `()` around your parameters hash, as already answered Ryan Bigg.

Answer (score 1):

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@sub_categories = @category.sub_categories # assumption: this doesn't return nil
page_opts = {:page => params[:page], :order => 'name', :per_page => @per_page}
@designs = @sub_categories.map {|sub_cat| sub_cat.designs.paginate(page_opts) }
```

Comment: I love the concise answer but i am getting this error now undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x1036be208> Extracted source (around line #37): 37:  <%= will_paginate @designs %>

Comment: Well, `@designs` is an `Array` of `WillPaginate::Collection` elements. It is not itself a pagination collection.